# Hooks for altering Views block output in Drupal 6

Tags: 7, hooks, views

I have a View in which i mention 3 fields then i displayed as a block.

I want to want to change value of these fields.

> Which hook will i use so i can change content to fields on page load ?
>
> I tried  hook_view, hook_block, they don't help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [hook_views_pre_render](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!docs!views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) to alter the results of the View before Views passes the data of for rendering.